# apt-get install via tunnel proxy but ssh only from client side

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, firewall, vpn, apt

So... this is my problem:

I can access to a VPN from my machine. I can access to a server in the VPN via SSH, but this machine has no access inside out because a firewall is blocking the reverse ssh connections. So I can't use Internet via tunnel to use apt-get.

[image: Lan configuration]

How can I emulate:

```
sudo ssh -D 9999 root@<machineoutsidevpn>
```

But from outside the VPN.
Or any way to use the Internet connection to install packages?

Comment: I tried with this solution: http://superuser.com/questions/370930/ssh-reverse-socks-tunnel using the command "ssh remotehost -R remoteport:localhost:localport "ssh -D 9050 localhost -p remoteport"" but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 52, accepted):

## Setup:

Computer A

- Has access to Internet
- Has access to Computer B
- SSH is installed

Computer B

- Doesn't have access to Internet
- OpenSSH Server is installed

---

## Steps:

1. ssh into Computer B **from** Computer A

   ```
   sudo ssh -R <selected port>:us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 user@computerb.host
   ```
2. Edit Computer B's `/etc/apt/apt.conf` to include the following lines:

   ```
   Acquire::http::Proxy "http://localhost:<selected port>";
   Acquire::https::Proxy "https://localhost:<selected port>";
   ```
3. Run your `apt-get update` or `install` or `upgrade` on Computer B and it should work.

---

## A few notes:

- You **HAVE** to keep the original session of ssh from Computer A to Computer B active while using Computer B to access apt-get repositories.
- You DON'T have to use the same ssh connection to utilize the tunnel (meaning if you have multiple ssh connection into Computer B, they should all work)

---

## Using Putty

This can also be achieved using Putty (assuming that Computer A is the Windows machine).

1. When starting the session, select SSH --> Tunnels
2. Source Port: `<selected port>`
3. Destination: `us.archive.ubuntu.com:80`
4. Select the "Remote" radio button
5. Select "Add" button
6. Configure your session as you normally would.
7. Follow steps 2 & 3 above

Comment: Thanks! You save my life. It worked for the official repositories, but... what if I need extra packages or use python pip.

Comment: I tried in computerA: ssh -R 8889:pypi.python.org:443 user@computerb.host and in computerB: sudo pip --proxy=https://localhost:8889 install <package>. But it doesn't work

Comment: @rasputino python pip present an entirely different problem.  I wasn't able to get it to work in the limited time I spent on this.  I just manually install packages instead.

Comment: for debian distro use: ftp.us.debian.org:80

Comment: This only partially works: It fails for most https traffic. Even if you make apt ignore the certificates, it still doesn't work. But it is good enough if you're lucky... some things might install.

Comment: is it possible to do it purely using apt's command lines in place of step 2? In my case, my account doesnt have sudo access

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

On computer B, do **not** change `/etc/apt/apt.conf`, I suggest to create/edit
`/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf` with this:

```
# "socks5h" means proxy with DNS resolving ability
Acquire {
  HTTP::proxy "socks5h://127.0.0.1:8080";
  HTTPS::proxy "socks5h://127.0.0.1:8080";
}
```

This will keep the proxy configuration separate from other APT configuration.

On computer A: run SSH e.g:

```
ssh -R 127.0.0.1:8080 user@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
```

On computer B you can verify that the proxy works as expected using curl eg:

```
curl -v --socks5 localhost:8080 http://security.debian.org/debian-security
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to enable SSH Tunneling. This lets you run an SSH session inside another protocol, this option lets you bypass the firewall by fooling it into thinking that the Incoming Connection is actually a http port 80 reply instead of port 21. an example is below, you may need to fine tweak it to your liking.

ssh -L 9000:serverIpAddress:80 user@example.com

Good luck!

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, I think all out connections are forbidden. I can connect from outside using the command "ssh -L 9000:serverIpAddress:80 user@example.com" but when I'm connected in the server inside tsocks doesn't work. (I previously configured tsocks on 127.0.0.1 and port 9000)

Comment: If its a deep packet inspecting Firewall, it will get pretty complicated. try find out what type of firewall you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Install proxychains and tmux: you might have luck with something like:

```
sudo ssh -R 8080:us.archive.ubuntu.com:80 user@computerb.host
echo 'Acquire::http::Proxy "http://localhost:8080";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
apt-get update
apt-get install proxychains tmux
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy.conf
```

Notice the last line there undid the apt proxy configuration?

After you have proxychains and tmux, you can get much more reliable operation, and without funky apt configuration changes, and pip / curl etc works too.

First, start up tmux. (quick primer, uses `CTRL-B` than another key, 'c' for another new shell, 'n/p' for cycling between shells, 'd' to detach and leave things running).

```
tmux
```

Next, we'll make a ssh connection from the isolated computer back to any computer it can SSH to which does have internet access, lets call it `server`.

```
ssh -f -NT -M -S ~/.ssh/ssh_socket_for_proxychains -D 127.0.0.1:17471 server
```

This doesn't seem like it's done anything, because it's running in the back ground. You can see it with `ps aux |grep ssh` or so.

Now, configure `/etc/proxychains.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/proxychains.conf
```

Change the last line from `socks4  127.0.0.1 9050` to `socks5  127.0.0.1 17471`.

Finally, you can now run things like `sudo proxychains apt upgrade -y` and `proxychains pip install ...` without having them fail.

As a bonus, you can detach the tmux session (CTRL-b,d) and come back to it later (ssh back in, then `tmux a`).

For raspberrypi's, it works if you change 'us.archive.ubuntu.com' to 'archive.raspberrypi.org', and for random debian you might have luck with 'ftp.us.debian.org'

For me, the use case is things like raspi's on a isolated static ip network, where I have another server with two network connections (one with internet access, another to the isolated lan) where it does not route: It's running trueNAS, and the lan is staying isolated.
But it does have opensshd that I can ssh into, and then ssh along to the pi.

In this case, its isolated lan ip address is the 'server' the pi connects back to. And its the pi that gets proxychains and tmux and can then be updated via apt.

Credit to James Mertz for the `ssh -R` part, but it only works with http traffic, anything that has an https URL will fail; and it won't work for pip: where things get fetched from a bunch of different random servers. Still, it's good enough to use to get proxychains.

The proxychains howto part came curtesy of https://yuzhangbit.github.io/tools/use-apt-get-behind-socks5-proxy/

Comment: Looks interesting. Would be good to get a bit of info about what the role of `proxychains` and `tmux` are in this setup, rather than just the how-to.